# Is there a distribution with an installer that can automatically do LVM over LUKS with everything aligned as needed?

Tags: partition, system-installation, lvm, ssd, luks

http://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2012/01/11/linux-ssd-partition-alignment-tips/ talks about aligning SSD partitions and LVM physical volumes.

http://rainbow.chard.org/2013/01/30/how-to-align-partitions-for-best-performance-using-parted/ refers to getting various parameters to be used in alignment.

I'm looking for a distro with an installer to do all of this automatically after I specify the partition sizes. It doesn't matter which one it is, as I can install something else afterwards.

Thanks!